Dual boot - 2 windows instances - add EFI to secondary drive
I have two copies of Win 11 installed on my computer.
They are installed on separate NVME drives.
Since I cannot remove those drives physically (also cannot disable them in BIOS) - there is only a single EFI partition present right now and I must use multi boot menu to select which system to boot.
Is there a way to add secondary EFI partition (as well as recovery partition) to second windows instance without removing NVME drives?
Desired outcome would be to be able to boot from old and new EFI partitions by using bios boot override as well as be able to boot from primary EFI partition and still be able to use windows boot menu to select desired system.

Manually create and format the EFI partition, then use bcdboot to install its contents. The tool will copy in all bootloader files, will generate a BCD with one entry that boots the specified OS, and will add an UEFI boot menu item (/d to disable that).
The partition should have the "EFI System Partition" type ID, which create part gpt in DISKPART will set automatically; and it must be formatted as FAT32. Excerpt from Microsoft docs (the "lab sample scripts" section):
DISKPART> create partition efi size=100
DISKPART> format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
DISKPART> assign letter="S"

bcdboot C:\Windows /f UEFI /s S: /v /d

(...then deassign the letter once everything is done.)
bcdboot will also install the bootloader at the "default" path so you can boot individual disks through UEFI. But if you want to have named UEFI boot entries, use Linux efibootmgr to create them.

Then manually create and format the WinRE partition, then use reagentc to register it. You might need to copy its contents manually from the other disk's recovery partition.
The recovery partition is NTFS, but has a special type ID and a specific attribute flag:
DISKPART>
create partition primary
format quick fs=ntfs label="Recovery"
assign letter="R"
set id="de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac"
gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001

See Microsoft docs for more specific instructions.

Thanks - I managed to achieve everything that I wanted!
For future references to other people:


recovery partition tutorial - https://www.wintips.org/how-to-create-a-recovery-partition-if-missing-on-windows-10-11/


also, be sure to remember to select appropriate disks / volumes when creating or changing any partition/volume.


Do remember to set Recovery partition size to about 1GB


